# Gnome-shell show battery percentage

Tags: gnome-shell

I'm running Gnome Shell 3.20.4.

Is there a way to show the battery percentage next to the icon?

Gnome Shell is using a reduced set of icons for the battery, thus not being accurate.

Since the icon dependent on the percentage, it must be available.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out it's pretty simple:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface show-battery-percentage true
```

And to turn it back off:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface show-battery-percentage false
```

Well, I hope this comes handy for someone ;)

---

Credits go to **joann**'s post on https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/818/battery-percentage/